# Need to clarify some concept of the relation of the class. new to programming

Tags: c#, class, subclass, inheritance

Here is the sample:

```
class A{
    class AA{}
}
class B:A{
}
```

For class A, We can say AA is the subclass of A. 
However, for class AA, A is the ???? of AA?

For class A, B is the child class of A
Can I say A is the ???? of B?

Comment: if AA is public then everybody know him, else only A know him....
B know A but A dn't knw B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AA` is a **nested** or **inner** type. It's not a subclass. `A` is the **containing** or **outer** type.

`B` derives from `A`. It's a **derived** class. `A` is the **base** class.

*See also:*

- [Inheritance (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx)
- [Nested Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx)

Comment: Your reference is very useful to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`AA` is referred to as a "nested" class.  Class `A` would be the container of class `AA`.  Class `AA` is not visible outside class `A` unless it is marked as public.  Class `B` is a child of class `A`.  Class `A` is a base class of class `B`.

Comment: I've got what I want from your answer. Thank you Dan.